# NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.PictureInPictureParams

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'am using the [EasyPermission](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions) library and when I want to accept a storage permission, my application crash with the following StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.PictureInPictureParams
     at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
     at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:2551)
     at java.lang.reflect.AbstractMethod.getParameterTypes(AbstractMethod.java:169)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:193)
     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1812)
     at pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions.runAnnotatedMethods(EasyPermissions.java:368)
     at pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(EasyPermissions.java:240)
     at com.my.app.base.BaseActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(BaseActivity.java:489)
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7458)
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7284)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4516)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.app.PictureInPictureParams" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app.debug-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.app..debug-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.my.app.debug-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
     at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:53)
     at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:2551) 
     at java.lang.reflect.AbstractMethod.getParameterTypes(AbstractMethod.java:169) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:193) 
     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1812) 
     at pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions.runAnnotatedMethods(EasyPermissions.java:368) 
     at pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(EasyPermissions.java:240) 
     at com.my.app.base.BaseActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(BaseActivity.java:489) 
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7458) 
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7284) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4516) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

What you should notice is that it happen on both **RELEASE** and **DEBUG** version.

Here is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release_config {
            [not showing it here]
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "x"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    // workaround for "duplicate files during packaging of APK" issue
    // see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/bl5Rc4Szpzg/wC8cylTWuIEJ
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

        //Workaround to an issue due to google play-services 11.0.0 + rxJava
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release_config
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix " - debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "public"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "public"
        }

        prod {

            dimension "public"
        }
    }
}

//Define gradle variables
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '27.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

    //Support Libraries
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'

    //Google Collections -> Known as Guava. Provides tools to work with collections.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'

    //Google FlexBox -> Flexible layout to handle unknown number of children.
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.3'

    //Fragment Args -> Library using annotation to simplify the process of passing arguments to a fragment
    compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:annotation:3.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:processor:3.0.2'

    //Dart -> Library using annotation to simplify the process of passing arguments to an activity
    compile 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart-processor:2.0.0'

    //Dagger -> Library used for dependencies injections
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'

    //GSON -> Library to simplify Json parsing
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    //Couchbase -> NoSQL Database Manager
    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android-sqlcipher:1.4.0'

    //Retrofit -> Library developed by Square. Used to communicate with Restful API.
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    //AVLoading -> Provides multiple loaders.
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

    //Crashlytics -> Crash reporting library. Developed by Fabric.
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //Faker -> Library to create fake data
    compile 'com.github.thiagokimo:faker:1.4.3'

    //MaterialSearchView -> Provides a styled material searchView.
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'

    //LovelyDialog -> Provide beautiful and easy to use dialogs
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.4'

    //TextDrawable -> Provides images with text, useful for profile avatar (eg: Gmail).
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'

    //2D ScrollView
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:twodscrollview:1.0.1'

    //RecyclerViewTools -> Tools for RecyclerView (Headers, Footers, Sections, etc).
    compile 'com.eyeem.recyclerviewtools:library:0.4.0'

    //RopeProgressBar -> A sweet animated progress bar
    compile 'com.github.cdeange:RopeProgressBar:0.1.2'

    //AsyncJob -> Simplify the use of AsyncTask.
    compile 'com.arasthel:asyncjob-library:1.0.3'

    //Simple -> Xml Parser
    compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }

    //RxAndroid -> Reactive Android. Library that implement Observable/Reactive pattern for Android.
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended to
    // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    //Leak Canary -> Detect memory leaks.
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'

    //Material about -> Library to build neat about page
    compile 'com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:2.2.1'

    //Stetho -> used to analyze application (database, shared-preferences, traffic network, etc)
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.robotpajamas.stetho:stetho-couchbase:0.2.0'
    compile project(path: ':security')

    //Apache commons lang 3 -> contains utilities such as ClassUtils
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'

    //ExpandableRecyclerView -> Implementation of ExpandableListView for RecyclerView
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'

    //TextDecorator -> Easy to implements span etc.
    compile 'com.tuyenmonkey:text-decorator:1.0.0'

    //EasyPermission -> Helper for Android-M permissions
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.0.0'

    // CompositeAndroid -> Library that make uses of plugins to inject into Activities and Fragments
    // instead of using inheritance trees.
    // contains CompositeActivity
    compile "com.pascalwelsch.compositeandroid:activity:26.0.0"
    // contains CompositeFragment and CompositeDialogFragment
    compile "com.pascalwelsch.compositeandroid:fragment:26.0.0"
    // core module (not required, only abstract classes and utils)
    compile "com.pascalwelsch.compositeandroid:core:26.0.0"
}
```

I already tried a few things:

1. Clean/Rebuild
2. Disabling Instant Run
3. Asked on the GitHub page of [EasyPermission](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions) but resulted in a 'not an error due to the library' (which is right)
4. Adding a file on "multiDexKeepFile"
5. Adding a file on "multiDexKeepProguard"

For the point 4 and 5 here is how I created my files (maybe I did it wrong):

**MultiDexKeepFile**

```
android/app/PictureInPictureParams.class
```

**MultiDexKeepProguard**

```
-keep class android.app.PictureInPictureParams
```

And I added them both on the root of my project and under the 'app' directory (same level as the gradle file). I obviously added the corresponding lines of the `multiDexKeepFile` and `multiDexKeepProguard` into the gradle file as well but it didn't changed anything.

I aslo checked inside the dex files of my APK but didn't find the `android.app.PictureInPictureParams`.

Nothing I tried fixed my issue. What should I do so?

Comment: `android.app.PictureInPictureParams` is part of the framework, not your app.  That class [was added in API Level 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PictureInPictureParams.html) and will not exist in older devices. You are running your app on an older device, and something about the annotation processing is triggering this crash. My guess is that you have the annotation on a method that references `PictureInPictureParams`, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Thank's for the information. You're right about the API level 26, I'm actually testing the application on a 24 API level. But my `min sdk` is 21 and I won't move it to 26 to resolve this issue. When you're talking about an annotation that makes a reference to `PictureInPictureParams`, how could I find that annotation? Because I'm not using the  `picture in picture` feature. It seems that this comes from the `EasyPermission` library because of `pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions.runAnnotatedMethods(EasyPermissions.java:368)` but that's the only hint I have.

Comment: "how could I find that annotation?" -- remove all of your `EasyPermission` annotations. Get the app running. Add in those annotations again, one a time, testing after each to see when the app breaks again. Then, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing your code, indicating which annotation was the one that triggered the break. Though, to be honest, a library from `googlesamples` does not fill me with confidence.

Comment: Ok thank you. I do not have a lot of annotation so that will be easy. But if not too personnal, why does `googlesamples` doesn't fill you with confidence? I found the library useful to remove boilerplate code but I might move out to the regular way of using permissions.

Comment: There are [20+ libraries that offer to help with runtime permissions](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/235?sort=updated). Few of them are advertised as "sample" code. Google's Android code from outside of official channels (e.g., support libraries) has a mixed record of results.

Comment: I am having the same trouble martin. Can you let us answer your question. I am having this issue because of https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/ but removing event bus is not an option for me. Looking forward for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain with some other library ([EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)) but with the same context as asked by OP. In android os version less than oreo, I was getting the crash logs.

Reference: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/595

Additional Reference for the same:

1. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/149
2. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/556

Owner of the GreenBot has also updated the FAQ for the same:
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/faq/

**Cause of error:**
The exception is thrown if the class has methods with a parameter that is unavailable to the API level of the device.

**Example**: the class `PersistableBundle` was added in API level 21. Along with the new class some new life cycle methods were introduced in the class Activity having `PersistableBundle` as a parameter, for example, `onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, *PersistableBundle* persistentState)`. Now, if you override this method and you try to register this Activity to `EventBus` on an older device, we have exactly the scenario described to cause to bug.

**Possible Suggestions:**

1. Maybe you overwrote a life cycle method with PersistableBundle just by accident. In that case just change to the method without PersistableBundle, for example onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState).
2. Use EventBus 3 with an subscriber index. This will avoid reflection
   and thus the problem altogether. As a positive side effect,
   registering subscribers and thus app startup time will be much
   faster.
3. Remove the offending method from your subscriber class. Either pull
   out the event handler methods into a new subscriber class, or pull
   out the offending method into a non-subscriber class.
4. If the offending method is public, make it non-public. This works
   because of some “plan b” logic EventBus applies: EventBus first
   calls getDeclaredMethods, which will fail. Next, EventBus will try
   again using the getMethods (“plan b”). The latter will succeed
   because getMethods only returns public methods. However, keep in
   mind that is the least efficient way in terms of performance (2
   reflection calls instead of 1 with getMethods considering the entire
   class hierarchy).

I used a private modifier for my problem [Suggetion #4].